# How to create a dynamic multi-colors TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `DataGrid`, then one column is a multi-colors `TextBlcok`.

But this column data will change by others view.

So, I think I need design a ViewModel to binding it.

Now, I am confuse how to create this TextBlock into my DataGrid column.

like:

[image]

Now, Call the `A` and `B` are property, `123` and `456` are date of property.

And User will change data of property `A` maybe like:

[image]

Or, User will add new data of property `C`, like:

[image]

Sure, Maybe clear data of property `B`, like:

[image]

All properties exist in model, but is not show necessarily on `TextBlock`. So if it has no any data, it will show nothing on this column.

By the way, User need to copy this column's content, so I want to use `TextBlock` for user selectable.

And binding `Run` of `TextBlock` for difference color's word.

Maybe this is a UserControl and add in `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` of `DataGrid`, but how to binding and dynamic create new `Run` of `TextBlock`?

Maybe others method I have no idea now.

I feel something is stuck in my head.

Help!

Comment: if you want dynamically change some style and behaviors, i think it's best to use AttachedProperties and in their callback to define styles for HasValue and noValue.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will to understand `AttachedProperties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given it a try. It is not a complete solution, but it will help you and take you little forward towards your solution. Maybe you can take it ahead from there. So, Here my code goes:

> Models:

```
public class DGCollection
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValues> KeyValues { get; set; }
    }

public class KeyValues
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

> ViewModel :

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            DGCollections = new ObservableCollection<DGCollection>();
            LoadData();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<DGCollection> _DGCollections;

        public ObservableCollection<DGCollection> DGCollections
        {
            get { return _DGCollections; }
            set
            {
                _DGCollections = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DGCollections");
            }
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            KeyValues obj1 = new KeyValues { Key = "A", Value = "123" };
            KeyValues obj2 = new KeyValues { Key = "B", Value = "456" };
            KeyValues obj3 = new KeyValues { Key = "C", Value = "789" };
            KeyValues obj4 = new KeyValues { Key = "D", Value = "101112" };
            List<KeyValues> lst = new List<KeyValues>();
            lst.Add(obj1);
            lst.Add(obj2);
            lst.Add(obj3);
            lst.Add(obj4);            
            DGCollections.Add(new DGCollection { ID = 1, KeyValues = lst });
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }

    }
```

> XAML :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AItemTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Key}" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" Text=" : " Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="2"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dG" ItemsSource="{Binding DGCollections}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding ID}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding KeyValues}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AItemTemplate}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

What I tried here is to create a DataGridTemplateColumn. Used ItemsControl inside it. And assigned a template to that ItemsControl. For this approach, you may have to make few changes in your model or have to change bindings from my example. Give it a try and let me know if you need any further help on this.

Comment: Oh, your answer is in my mind. but sorry, I have no computer now, may you wait me to try it about last weekend? I am confuse that the list will run, this is I feel stuck and worry. So, thanks and wait me.

Comment: That's fine. You can give this a try and let me know if this is useful. I will try to help you out.

Comment: Sure! BTY, maybe I will use `Run` in `AItemTemplate`. like: <TextBlock><Run/>...</TextBlock> , because I need it is ONE TextBlock to Editable by double-click.

Comment: Sure, you can use run instead of 3 diff textblocks. Make sure to use diff foreground color for all those run tags.

Comment: I try to implement in my project, but it's not work, maybe I will copy your code in a empty project and try again. Sorry for your wait, I am busy this week.

Comment: No problem, Let me know if you face any issue with new project.

Comment: What need to use `ItemTemplate`? How can I do no use template?

Comment: Sorry 黃柏森, I didn't get your question. Can you please rephrase it.

Comment: Oh, OK, my fault. I mean, Can I take out `ItemTemplate` of `ItemsControl`, and design Items in original `<DataTemplate>` content. Sorry, my english maybe not good.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, if I use `DataGridTextColumn`, I can set `IsReadOnly` to False so that  the `TextBlock` can be edit. But how to set `IsReadOnly` on `TextBlock` of `ItemsControl `?

Comment: @黃柏森 I tried updated answer. Looks like there is some issue with Items. Maybe you can go for my older answer. If you need I can revert to older version

Comment: Oh, OK. I can follow your older answer. But I want to know what's wrong?

Comment: Can you revert your answer? Then, I will choice your.

Comment: Sure, i don't have computer now but will do it tomorrow.

Comment: @黃柏森 I have reverted answer. Please have a look.